# Decrypting RSTR sent from STS

Tags: c#, adfs2.0, federated-identity

I developed a custom service provider and federated authentication to an STS. The claims in the requsted security token of the RSTR sent by the STS are encrypted.

The RSTR is sent in the wresult parameter.

The token looks a bit like this :

```
<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">...<t:RequestedSecurityToken><xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">...
```

The problem is that I want to have the RSTR encrypted. I saw that the  tag is responsible of decrypting the received tokens. I added it , at first I had errors about finding the certificate specified in that tag, but after I didn't had errors no more , the RSTR still has that  tag ...

I applied that tag for a sharepoint application in order to decrypt , it worked fine , but in my web.config , it doesn't.

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to decrypt the token programmatically, can't retrieve the key , while I encrypted and decrypted with the certificate the STS used to encrypt and which , btw , subject is present in the EncryptedData tag

Comment: I also , just to check , put another certificate in the serviceCertificate tag ... It didn't give me an error like .... " bro the certificate you've put can't decrypt the incoming requested security token included in the RSTR " .... Help guys